# TensorFlow object detection API fine tune checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a model from scratch ,in that case what should I put in fine_tune_checkpoint value in Protobuf file.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. It should initialize your entire model.

If for some reason that doesn't work for you, you can give it a checkpoint of something else entirely. The API builds the graph of the model, and compares between its variables to the variables in the checkpoint (both names and shapes), and every variable it doesn't find - it initializes.